# AWS ECR CF template fails with 'Invalid repository policy provided'

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

This CF template fails:

```
  MyECSrepo:
    Type: "AWS::ECR::Repository"
    Properties:
      RepositoryName: !Ref RepoName
      RepositoryPolicyText:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Sid: AllowAll
            Effect: Allow
            Principal: 
              AWS:
                - arn:aws:iam::00000000000:group/admin
            Action:
          - "ecr:*"
```

The stack creation produces this error:

Invalid parameter at 'PolicyText' failed to satisfy constraint: 'Invalid repository policy provided'

What might the problem be?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Having a read of the documentation around [ECR Repository Policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/set-repository-policy.html), it turns out it's limited to users and root accounts for the Principal list. So you will probably need to swap out to listing all the users you want to give access to.

[Amazon documentation has some samples](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/RepositoryPolicyExamples.html) has some examples of what you can do with it.

Comment: Learning: You can also only reference users in as principle if they exist. Generic once for testing will also fail!

Comment: It works for roles too (not only users and root accounts).

Answer (score 5):

Just in case duke of muppets link breaks, here is an example. I had trouble today with the automatically created json. This seemed to fix it.

```
    {
      "Version": "2008-10-17",
      "Statement": [
        {
          "Sid": "AllowPushPull",
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<<id number of root user here>>:user/<<some iam user>>"
          },
          "Action": [
            "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
            "ecr:BatchGetImage",
            "ecr:CompleteLayerUpload",
            "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
            "ecr:InitiateLayerUpload",
            "ecr:PutImage",
            "ecr:UploadLayerPart"
          ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: The part of `:user/<<some iam user>>` was the key aspect I had wrong, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A suitable solution might be in using a `RoleArn` instead of groups (what doesn't work) ...and/or IAM users

```
ECR:
    Type: AWS::ECR::Repository
    Properties:
        RepositoryPolicyText:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
                -
                  Sid: AllowPushPull
                  Effect: Allow
                  Principal:
                    AWS:
                      - !Sub arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/${MyPreparedRole}
                  Action:
                    - "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer"
                    - "ecr:..."
```

The role "MyPreparedRole" can be provided within a group.

Answer (score 1):

we had the same problem today and it turned out the IAM user name given in the policy text was wrong. Due to that, stack got into unrecoverable deleted_failed mode and we had to delete the stack and re-created it.