# I am getting an error while using aws cli to set repository policy for aws ecr

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-ecr

Following is the error massage for running

aws ecr set-repository-policy --repository-name "${algorithm_name}" --policy-text policy.json

error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the SetRepositoryPolicy operation: Invalid parameter at 'PolicyText' failed to satisfy constraint: 'Invalid repository policy provided'.

Comment: Looks something in your `policy.json` is not valid one. Can you update your question with the `policy.json` content. Also see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/repository-policy-examples.html

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46001417/aws-ecr-cf-template-fails-with-invalid-repository-policy-provided this helps

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `policy.json` as a literal string to the command. To pass the contents of the file named `policy.json` you need to do the following, just like in the examples shown in [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecr/set-repository-policy.html#examples):

```
aws ecr set-repository-policy --repository-name "${algorithm_name}" --policy-text file://policy.json
```